# datatable with html content

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datatable

I am using `jquery` `datatable` and data input in`json` format.

```
$('#newItemBasketTab').dataTable({
  "aaData": result.itembasketdata,
  "aoColumns": 
  [
     {"mDataProp": "nic5dcodename"},
     {"mDataProp": "asiccprodcodename"},
     {"mDataProp": "unit_name"},
     {"mDataProp": "prod_quantity"},
     {"mDataProp": "prod_value"}
  ]
});
```

Now I want to place a checkbox in first column of `datatable` and based on an ID field in `json` data, the `checkbox` needs to be `checked` or `unchecked`. Is it possible to add html content to `datatable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mrender` property -

```
$('#newItemBasketTab').dataTable({
  "aaData": result.itembasketdata,
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
      "aTargets": [ 0 ],
      "mData": "ID",
      "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
        var checked = "checked";
        if(data) { checked = "checked"; }
        return "<input type='checkbox' checked='" + checked + "'>";
      }
    },
    {"mData": "nic5dcodename"},
    {"mData": "asiccprodcodename"},
    {"mData": "unit_name"},
    {"mData": "prod_quantity"},
    {"mData": "prod_value"}
  ]
});
```

[DOCS](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Answer (score 1):

You code will look like,

```
$('#newItemBasketTab').dataTable({
  "aaData": result.itembasketdata,
  "aoColumns": 
  [
     {"mDataProp": "Selection", 
      "fnRender":function(obj, type){
                   if(obj.aData['ID'])
                        return "<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>"
                   else
                        return "<input type='checkbox'>"
                 }
     }
     {"mDataProp": "nic5dcodename"},
     {"mDataProp": "asiccprodcodename"},
     {"mDataProp": "unit_name"},
     {"mDataProp": "prod_quantity"},
     {"mDataProp": "prod_value"}
  ]
});
```

You can add any html code that you want to display in `fnRender` function